# $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); No results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is not giving results, when i try with $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); it gives me 3 times the same result.

```
    $sql = "SELECT char_name, pvpkills FROM characters WHERE accesslevel=:normalPlayer AND pvpkills>=:minPvp ORDER BY pvpkills DESC LIMIT :maxRows";
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':normalPlayer', $normalPlayer, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':minPvp', $minPvp, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':maxRows', $maxRows, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
            $cuentaPvp = $stmt->rowCount();
            $resPvp = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            Session::init();
            Session::set('cuenta_pvp', $cuentaPvp);

            for($i = 0; $i<$cuentaPvp; $i++){
                Session::set('pvp_name'.$i, $resPvp['char_name']);
                Session::set('pvp_count'.$i, $resPvp['pvpkills']);
            }
```

Comment: You're not actually looping through `$resPvp` that's why you get the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `fetchAll` is an array of structures so you may replace the `for` statement with:

```
foreach ($resPvp as $key => $value) {
    Session::set('pvp_name' . $key, $value['char_name']);
    Session::set('pvp_count' . $key, $value['pvpkills']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a while-loop with `$stmt->fetchAll(...)`?

Comment: Because `fetchAll` fetches all immediately. Your C.O.

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop to the code below:

```
for($i = 0; $i<$cuentaPvp; $i++){
                Session::set('pvp_name'.$i, $resPvp[$i]['char_name']);
                Session::set('pvp_count'.$i, $resPvp[$i]['pvpkills']);
            }
```